# some method to mark totally wrong answers other than downvote

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I was searching answer of my question from already answered questions on stackoverflow. I found entries(answers and comments) for similar questions which can not be right at the same time. All of them were upvoted significantly.

i strongly suggest to give privilege to advanced experts, with some threshold value for reputation, to mark answers as wrong answers with some explanation if needed. Perhaps on negative side it will reduce research capabilities but it is definite that it will reduce effort time to reach correct answer

Answer (score 12):

Down-votes **are** for wrong answers. You can also leave a comment explaining why the answer is wrong.

If an answer is scoring less than zero it's eligible for 20k+ users to vote to delete it. The fact that these answers are scoring highly means that they were probably correct/useful at some point in the past.

There's no need for an extra privilege.

Comment: ah my question got so many down votes and opposition got so many upvotes. Still I am in favor to some mechanism by which an expert with reputation threshold (50k,75k and above) be privileged to mark the answer as correct,irrespective of acceptance by originator of question, and this marking should be shown to all others along with asking member acceptance. This method will develop trust on the answer for others to try as first option :)